# Is it possible to modify Web Api Parameter (FromUri) inside Action Filter?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, action-filter

My Web API receives a param object consisting of (DateTime) `dateFrom`, (DateTime) `dateTo`.

Currently I preprocess the parameter inside my API entry function, which, is repetitive throughout the API.

I wish I could access and **modify** the parameter before it enters the API entry function.

So I have the action filter below:

```
public class MyActionParamFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        // pre-processing
        object param;
        object param2;
        actionContext.Request.Properties.TryGetValue("dateFrom", out param);
        actionContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("dateFrom", out param2);
    }
}
```

[image]

From the image, it is clearly that i have passed the parameters to the API. But I have no idea why `param` and `param2` are null...

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: found this after posting this..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169378/parameter-binding-in-asp-net-web-api
would continue tomorrow....

Answer (score 0):

Finally I follow the answer here:
[Change webapi controller action parameter in delegatinghandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555222/change-webapi-controller-action-parameter-in-delegatinghandler)

Technically, it is to modify `actionContext.ActionArguments`.

But I am not too sure if this is 'Best practice' or something.. Let me know your thought if you think i am in the wrong direction of design.